# Multiple UICollectionViews with the same Datasource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a couple of `collectionView`s within the same view and decided to let the same object handle the datasource duties. I'm having issues with `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` method when the number of items I want to display differs between them (which is all the time except when tested with a dummy single return statement). In the future the number will be pulled dynamically but just for debugging I plugged in static values.

The method pretty much goes:

```
if (cv == self.articlesView) {        
    return 4;
} else if (cv == self.journalsView) {
    return 4;
} else if (cv == self.algorithmsView) {
    return 6;
}
return 10; // this never actually runs
```

Cells are created in a very basic way at this point (I'm just starting on this app):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];        
    return cell;
}
```

and I run the following for each of my collectionViews in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[cv registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

The error I get is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and it's attached to the `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` line in the app delegate.

If I change the number of items for the last `collectionView` from 6 to 3 (basically, make it smaller than all the others), the app runs but now all collectionViews have the smaller number of items, not just the last one (it looks like the first time iOS runs `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` it does it for that last collectionView).

So it looks like the first time the method runs, the result somehow sticks and gets applied to all the others, and then out of bounds error appears. Yet I cannot figure out how to fix, or find anything wrong with my very minimal code.

Answer (score 1):

The bug in this case originated from the fact that I was not only reusing the same object for `delegate` and `dataSource`, but that I used the same `UICollectionViewLayout` for all `collectionView`s. I was applying some customizations to the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` object, and since I wanted the same customizations for all views, I just used the same object. Once I changed it to have a distinct layout object for each view, and just apply customizations in a loop to all of them - no more crashes!

Answer (score 0):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` indicates that you have a memory error. First, make sure you're using ARC. Then make sure you're using accessors rather than directly accessing your ivars. Finally, run the static analyzer, and look for errors there.

That said, I would recommend subclassing your data source for each view, and using method overrides to implement the logic differences, rather than having a single data source for all of them with conditional logic. For the cost of a couple of objects, you get a cleaner separation of functionality and likely simpler debugging of your memory error.